# How to create an alert the fade after a duration in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, alert, vuetify.js

How to create an [Alert](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/alerts/) in *Vuetify* that fade after specified number of seconds, similarly to the alerts in [Bootstrap Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/alert/). I tried this:

```
<template>
  <transition name="fade">
    <v-alert v-show="visible" v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
      <slot></slot>
    </v-alert>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: true,
  data() {
    return {
      visible: true,
      timer: null
    };
  },
  props: {
    duration: {
      required: true,
      type: Number
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fade() {
      let value = parseInt(Math.max(this.duration, 0));
      if (value != 0)
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => (this.visible = false), 1000 * value);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fade();
  }
};
</script>
```

Usage in other components:

```
    <vt-alert
      v-if="hasMessage()"
      :type="message.type"
      :duration="message.duration"
    >{{message.body}}</vt-alert>
```

`hasMessage` is utility function which check if the message is set.

But this did not work. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754460/component-does-not-rerender-after-props-get-updated-vuejs),

Comment: So what's not working? Does it not show? Does it not disappear after duration, or are you saying there is no fade animation?

Comment: @Zim It is all described in the provided link. Anyway, it only works for the first time the message objects is set, latter it displays nothing. I thought I may use the`updated` hook,  but the docs says I should avoid altering the state inside this hooks, which make sense.

Comment: The question is clear, I described what I have tried and  the problems are detailed in other SO question. So if you gonna downvote at least mention the reason or flag.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the question isn't clear based on the title, and it almost looks like you're asking the same question twice. Why didn't you follow-up with the comments in the other question?

Comment: @Zim I am not saying you are the downvoter, I do not know how you concluded that. I followed the comments but nothing. This question is like: I have tried in my way and I failed can any one suggest how to solve this in a different way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No need for so much code and custom ideas** :) **Use vuetify `API` (Less code = easier to maintain):**

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/alerts/#api

#### A. Show/Hide

The alert get value (**false** => hide. **True** => show).

```
<v-alert :value="alert">
```

```
data () {
  return {
   alert: false,
}
```

Toggle `alert` to `true`/`false` on click, hover, timer or any logic you want.

**Docs toogle example:** https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/alerts/#transition

### B. transition props

Use any build-in transition you want. List her:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/transitions/#motion

`<v-alert transition="fade-transition">`

### A+B: Basic "hello world" example

On click show alert & `slide-y-transition` out after 3 seconds.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      alert: false,
    }
  },
  // define methods under the `methods` object
  methods: {
    hide_alert: function (event) {
      console.log('Hide')
      // `event` is the native DOM event
      window.setInterval(() => {
        this.alert = false;
        console.log("hide alert after 3 seconds");
      }, 3000)    
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    if(alert){
      this.hide_alert();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.18/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <div class="text-center mb-4">
        <v-btn
               color="primary"
               @click="alert = true"
               >
          Show alert? {{alert}}
        </v-btn>
      </div>
      <v-alert
               :value="alert"
               color="pink"
               dark
               border="top"
               icon="mdi-home"
               transition="slide-y-transition"
               >
        Phasellus tempus. Fusce ac felis sit amet ligula pharetra condimentum. In dui magna, posuere eget, vestibulum et, tempor auctor, justo. Pellentesque posuere. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo.

        Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Phasellus magna. Cras risus ipsum, faucibus ut, ullamcorper id, varius ac, leo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent turpis.
      </v-alert>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.18/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

### Extra features example

Show timer (3..2..1) when the alert visible + toggle the alert on a button click.

About `dismissible` the best idea is to create a custom `X` button (And use the same show/hide function) ***Until the API gives more options related to this feature (Styling/position and so on).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      message: "show alert? - ",
      alert: false,
      countDown: {
        timer: "3",
        show: false
      },
    }
  },
  // define methods under the `methods` object
  methods: {
    show_alert_and_fade: function(){
      /* toogle alert on click */
      this.alert = !this.alert; 
      /* hide alert after 3 seconds */
      this.resetTimer();
      this.countDownTimer();
      /*  If alert visible - setTimeout() => only executed once */
      if(this.alert == true){
        myTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
          this.alert = false;
          console.log("Case 1: Time ends - hide alert");
        }, 3000);
      }else{
        /* If alert hidden - clear setTimeout */
        console.log("Case 2: User Hide alert by click - stop setTimeout");
        clearTimeout(myTimer);
        this.resetTimer();
      }
    },
    dismissible_close (value) {
      this.alert = value;
      this.resetTimer();
    },
    /*  recursion function - run time if remain time and alert if visible */ 
    countDownTimer() {
      if(this.countDown.timer > 0 && this.alert) {
        this.countDown.show = true;
        var myTimer = setTimeout(() => {
          this.countDown.timer -= 1;
          this.countDownTimer();
        }, 1000)
        }
      else{
        /* do something */
        this.resetTimer();
      }
    },
    resetTimer(){
      this.countDown.timer = 3;    
    },
    hideTimer(){
      this.countDown.show = false; 
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body{
  padding: 10px;
}

#close_btn{
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.18/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <div class="text-center mb-4">

        <!-- remove countDown for demo only -->

        <v-btn
               v-bind:color="alert ? 'success' : 'error'"
               @click="show_alert_and_fade"
               v-bind:class="{ active: alert }"
               >
          {{message}} <b> {{alert}}</b>

        </v-btn>

        <v-badge v-if="alert"
                 :content="countDown.timer"
                 :value="countDown.timer"
                 color="red"
                 overlap
                 >
        </v-badge>
      </div>
      <v-alert
               :value="alert"
               color="success"
               dark
               border="top"
               icon="mdi-home"
               transition="slide-y-transition"
               @input="dismissible_close"
               >
        <div id="close_btn">
          <v-btn  color="success" fab x-small @click="show_alert_and_fade">
            <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </div>

        <div class="pt-6 pr-6">
          <p>
            Phasellus tempus. Fusce ac felis sit amet ligula pharetra condimentum. In dui magna, posuere eget, vestibulum et, tempor auctor, justo. Pellentesque posuere. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo.
          </p>
          <p>
            Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Phasellus magna. Cras risus ipsum, faucibus ut, ullamcorper id, varius ac, leo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent turpis.
          </p>

        </div>
      </v-alert>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.18/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mark as solution to close this topic (I think this is the most basic/simple way to solve this issue).

Comment: @EzraSiton You should maybe bind to the alerts `v-model` instead of `:value` to bind it correctly. Currently if you dismiss it yourself early, the `alert` data prop doesn't turn back until the setTimeout finishes, but if you use `v-model` it will.